# str object is not callable while importing the dataset on jupyter notebook. what to do?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataset, read.csv

I tried to import the dataset on jupyter notebook. But it indicates error as str object is not callable,even the pathway of the file are obsolutely okay.
or Are there any problems with anaconda? help me out!!

here is my code after importing the libraries:

```
df=pd.read_csv('Nutrients.csv')
```

Even everything is okay it still shows str object is not callable
Now i need to load the dataset.

Comment: Sounds like you mistakenly assigned `pd.read_csv` to a string, so it is no longer a function.  I believe exiting and restarting the notebook will undo that assignment.

Comment: Exit the notebook and re-start it, exactly as I said.  Did you try that?

Comment: yahh!! i tried but still its not working.Now i can load the dataset but it still shows str object is not callable while plotting.what to do now?

Comment: Look in your code for anywhere that you assign `pd.read_csv = "some string"`.

Answer (score 0):

In [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), the string which is passed inside as a parameter is the name of the file. If the file does not exist, then python just considers the value as a string which in your case is the same.

Try checking out the location of the jupyter notebook that you are running the code in and the file you want to access. According to your code, they should be in the same location.

Comment: Actually,it is in the same file,if that is the case then the error should be like no file such directory exists!!but here it is different..the str object is not callable occurs once i start plotting the variables

Comment: can you share the folder structure in which the jupyter notebook and Nutrients.csv is present?